# Is there a way to detect the final workflow run status in github action?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow which includes many jobs. Some of the jobs are dynamically run via `matrix`. I need a way to report the workflow final build status at the end. How can I define a `action` that is only triggered when all jobs finish and get the current workflow run status?

I can have a `action` which has a condition as always:

```
- id: workflow-run-status-check
  if: always()
  needs: # all jobs
  run: |
    # how can I find out if there is any job fail?
```

but I don't know how to make it work for:

- how can I make the action depend on all jobs (including the dynamic ones)? Some of the jobs may not run every time.
- how can I find if there is any job failed? I know how to find a job status if I know the job id. but how can I find all jobs' status without knowing their id?

Comment: You can have a separate job with `if: always()` check and then use `needs` to wait on the rest of the jobs. To check the jobs status, you can dump `needs` context as JSON i.e. `toJson(needs)` and use its `result` for your decision making.

Comment: Here's a sample [workflow](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/6596920577/workflow) with a test [run](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/6596920577) highlighting the above idea. You can enhance it according to your own use case.